# Angular 6: Access to child of child component (from parent one)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular6, angular7

How to access (call certain methods) of child components of (2) children componenet s of some parent (container) component; i.e, Having `ParentCmp` holding inside template two children components (their selectors + template refs), and call certain methods of `LoadingPanels` inside those (two children) components:

`ParentCmp.html`:
....

```
<child1 #child1></child1>
<child2 #child2></child2>
```

`ParentCmp.ts`:

```
  @ViewChild('child1', read: ComponentRef<child1Cmp>) child1Cmp: ComponentRef<InvitationsBarComponent>;
  @ViewChild('child2') meetingsBarCmp: Child2Cmp;
...

child1Cmp.instance.loadingPnl.load(() => {....});
child2Cmp.loadingPnl.load(() => {....});
```

?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Could they communicate via a service instead? See https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Child1Component } from './child1/child1.component';
import { Child2Component } from './child2/child2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(Child1Component) child1: Child1Component;
  @ViewChild(Child2Component) child2: Child2Component;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.child1.child1Method();
    this.child2.child2Method();
  }

}
```

And in your Template:

```
<child1></child1>

<child2></child2>
```

**PS:** You can be sure to get access to the Child Component Instances in the `ngAfterViewInit` as that's when the view would be completely loaded.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/view-child-eg-stack-overflow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Well, not really... need to access child of child (!) (not the direct child - that one is obvious); THE child (of child) is kinda dynamic component (loader component taking observer function as a param (@Input) and after it completes - emits (letting know it's parent component (the "first" child - child1)

Comment: I think it would be a pretty good idea to update your question with this detail. Your question doesn't directly imply that a child of child access is required.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage ViewChild to call a method of child 2 in the parent component.
Have a look at the following.

Parent:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Child1Component } from './child1/child1.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '
        <div>
        <child1 #Child1Component></child1>
        </div>',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(Child1Component) child1?: Child1Component;

  customMethod() {
    this.child1?.child2?.someMethodOfChild2();

  }
```

Child 1:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Child2Component } from './child2/child2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'child1',
  templateUrl: '
        <div>
        <child2 #Child2Component></child2>
        </div>',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(Child2Component) child2?: Child2Component;

}
```